# Import backlinks from google analytics with PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm trying to import my backlinks from Google Analytics API with PHP. I have tried with the Analytics API, but I can not find the correct data. 
In search console, I can find all the links to my page, but from Analytics ga:FullReferrer, I only get links that others have clicked to come to my page. It's not the same list at all.

I have tried https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ and can not find the correct list. Do I look in the wrong places? Is there another API for Google Search Console?

```
function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
  $optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:fullReferrer, ga:source',
    'max-results' => '50000');

  return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:' . $profileId,
      '2005-01-01',
      'today',
      'ga:sessions', $optParams);
}
```

This returns links people have clicked. But I want the list from Google Search Console "Links to your page".

Any help is much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from Analytics ga:FullReferrer, I only get links that others have
>   clicked to come to my page

Google Analytics only records interactions with your page, so this is by design. Search console has an API, too, but [judging from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query) this will not give you referrer info.